# Bootstrap column order mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I currently have this:

```html
<div class="row" id="sobre-dr">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
             data
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          text
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
          image
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="sobre-dr">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
          image
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
          text
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 ">
          data
   </div>
</div>
```

I need it to look like this on the mobile:
date
text
image
I can not get someone to help me?

Comment: Why are you using full-width (12-col) divs if you don't want full-width divs? Have you read the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)?

Comment: yes I want full width in xs the question is how do I change the positions?

Comment: You're not getting much response because your question isn't clear at all. Use punctuation and code formatting to make it more clear. Right now it looks like you want the three items to be inline on a single row for mobile.

Comment: This might help you: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering